# GPLv3 licensing and Software-as-a-Service web apps

Tags: licensing, software-as-a-service

I am trying to figure out once and for all how the GPLv3 interacts with web applications, specifically SaaS applications.  I haven't been able to find a concrete answer about this.

Let's say I have a SaaS web app that users can purchase a monthly subscription to and access.  The source code is **not** distributed or made available to the customers in any way, shape or form and their only interaction is via the website and any APIs that I've provided via web services.

If I am using a third-party library licensed under the **GPLv3**, let's say a UI toolkit like Telerik's "KendoUI" (the open source version of which is licensed under GPLv3), then am I required to provide the source code for my web app (and therefore, in effect, make it worthless to sell as the source code would be readily available)?

I am aware that the Affero GPL *does* require this and was specifically created to close the "loophole" wherein you could use open-source libraries in a web app and never have to release your own source code (which IMO kind of defeats the purpose of a web app, but neither here nor there), but it doesn't appear that the standard GPLv3 license has this clause (in fact it appears to have been taken out specifically because of the backlash it would cause).

Is this understanding correct?  In other words, unless I want to open source my proprietary application, I should steer clear of anything using the Affero GPL, but the GPLv3 and others are fine as the "loophole" still exists within those?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a website running modified GPL software have an obligation to release their changes?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132485/),  [If I used GPL code in server side app, what if any of my code do I need to release?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/210212/), [What constitutes “distributing” for LGPL v3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131264/) and [Using GPL libraries without modification on a commercial website, do I need to make my source code available?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/)

Comment: See also on Stack Overflow [If I use GNU GPL code with my own server-side code, do I need to open my server-side code as GPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351119/if-i-use-gnu-gpl-code-with-my-own-server-side-code-do-i-need-to-open-my-server) and [Difference between Affero-GPL and GPLv3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127246/difference-between-affero-gpl-and-gplv3)

Comment: Since JavaScript is the new assembler, the third party libraries you use might cause executable code to be sent to the browser. If that code is GPL licenced without an exemption such as in the Bison licence, you might need to open your source code.